# "shader=interp" has no effect when using pgfplot plots surface

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-3dplot

I want to plot a surface with the style showed in the "Manual for Package pgfplots" using [this data](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ahthsev5X2HBhLFp0J_THuozhNUQaA):
[image: wanted]
However, I only got this:
[image]
Here is my code (LuaLatex):

```
\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[view/h=40,
colorbar horizontal,
xlabel=$x$, ylabel=$y$,]
\addplot3[surf,mesh/ordering=y varies,patch, patch type=rectangle, mark=none,shader=interp] file {
pu1pr2raw.dat
}; 
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
```

It really makes me suffer and I can not find a fix (maybe because I am a newbie). I have to go to sleep now, forgive me if I reply later.

Comment: Please provide a complete [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/121799), not just a fragment.

Comment: Thanks for reminding. I use a template of a journal, the pgfcompact factor is1.14, and there is nothing special. I can successfully get some sample in the manual for package pgfplots.:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

is created by

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  width=10cm,
  height=5cm,
  small,
  colorbar]

  \addplot3[surf,mesh/ordering=y varies,shader=interp,%patch,patch type=rectangle,
  mark=none] table {sample.dat}; 
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Here, I used only a subset of your huge data file (because of the long compilation time and the fact that I did not want to touch temf.cnf in order to increase the memory). More importantly, in accordance to the example on p. 34 of the pgfplots manual, I added an empty line whenever the first coordinate changes. (In your data, this amounts to adding an empty line after `y` hits `960.`.)